# Selecting Key,Value pairs from Key values in another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to select all of the key,values from one dictionary (imgs_dict) that have a key that appears in another dictionary (train_data_labels) and save the result into a third dictionary (training_images). One of the two original dictionaries has keys that are stored as numeric values (train_data_labels) and one is stored as a string (imgs_dict), so I first try to convert the key values of train_data_labels to a string and add leading zeros to match structure of imgs_dict, but this creates a list rather than a dictionary.

```
# Add leading zeros and convert key values to strings to allow referencing the image dictionary
training_ids=[str(k).zfill(5) for k in train_data_label]
```

After this I am trying to pull the image ids appearing in training_ids from imgs_dict, this appears to work but creates a list rather than a dictionary.

```
# Pull the training images from the total image set and save in a training images dictionary
training_images=[imgs_dict[i] for i in training_ids if i in imgs_dict]
```

It seems like there should be a straight forward way to save a new dictionary with altered keys, then select certain dictionary items that you want from another dictionary based on another list or dictionary but I'm having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension instead of the second list comp.

```py
training_images = {key: imgs_dict[key] for key in training_ids if key in imgs_dict}
```

Comment: I think that gets at the second part so thanks there. Still trying to understand how to get the first part before I can test it though.

Comment: Why does the first one need to be a dictionary at all? Is it not just a intermediate list with the converted keys?

Comment: It's a fair point, and I'm open to being wrong here as I'm very new to Python and image processing stuff but I was trying to keep it as a dictionary so I could later tie specific image classifications to their image id. Maybe I need to rethink that part.